# save 2 seekbars using shared preferences

Tags: android

I am developing app where i have two seekbars & i want to store their progress using share preferences so that whenever user will open that app he should get last changes made by him. I have done with saving 1 seekbar but not getting proper ans in case of 2 seekbars. can you please help me

```
public class Apartment extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    SeekBar seekBar,Seekbar; 

    private int newProgressValue,currentProgress;
    private int newProgressValue1,currentProgress1;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,sharedPreferences1 ;
    private String Key_PROGRESS = "key_progress";
    private String Key = "key_value";
    private String PREFERENCE_PROGRESS = "preference_progress";
    private String Key_PROGRESS1 = "key_progress1";
    private String Key1 = "key_value1";
    private String PREFERENCE_PROGRESS1 = "preference_progress1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_PROGRESS , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt(Key_PROGRESS, 0);


        sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_PROGRESS1 , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentProgress1 = sharedPreferences1.getInt(Key_PROGRESS1, 0);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apart);
        seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        Seekbar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        int max = 5;
        seekBar.setMax(max);
        Seekbar.setMax(max);
        seekBar.setProgress(currentProgress);
        Seekbar.setProgress(currentProgress1);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
Seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    }
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar ) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

newProgressValue = seekBar.getProgress();

        currentProgress = newProgressValue ;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS, newProgressValue);

        editor.commit();

    }
    public void onStopTrackingTouch1(SeekBar Seekbar) {

newProgressValue1 = Seekbar.getProgress();

        currentProgress1 = newProgressValue1 ;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
        editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS1, newProgressValue1);

        editor.commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onStopTrackingTouch1(SeekBar Seekbar) {

        newProgressValue1 = Seekbar.getProgress();

        currentProgress1 = newProgressValue1 ;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
        editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS1, newProgressValue1);

        editor.commit();

    }
```

this method will never be called. This is way you can get only the value of one `Seekbar`

You shoud register two differents implementaion of the `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`, one for the first `SeekBar` and one for the latter. You can do throug anonmyus inner class:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       currentProgress = newProgressValue ;

       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS, newProgressValue);

       editor.commit();

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
}
});


   Seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            newProgressValue1 = Seekbar.getProgress();

            currentProgress1 = newProgressValue1 ;

             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
             editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS1, newProgressValue1);

             editor.commit();

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a really bad way of naming your variables.  Instead of calling them `seekbar` and `Seekbar`, you'd be better off calling them `seekbar1` and `seekbar2`.  However, keeping with your variable names...  Your problem is that you're using the same listener - therefore the same method `onStopTrackingTouch` will be called for both SeekBars.  Just adding `onStopTrackingTouch1` does nothing.  Instead, you need to check which of the two invoked the method and deal with it accordingly; something like this:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
    if(seek == seekbar) {
        newProgressValue = seekbar.getProgress();
        currentProgress = newProgressValue;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS, newProgressValue);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else if(seek == Seekbar) {
        newProgressValue1 = Seekbar.getProgress();
        currentProgress1 = newProgressValue1 ;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
        editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS1, newProgressValue1);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

I am not approving your use of variable names, nor commenting on your code structure - just pointing out why you're experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same listener for both the seekbars without checking with one to use, here is the correct code:

```
public class Apartment extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

SeekBar seekBar, Seekbar;

private int newProgressValue, currentProgress;
private int newProgressValue1, currentProgress1;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, sharedPreferences1;
private String Key_PROGRESS = "key_progress";
private String Key = "key_value";
private String PREFERENCE_PROGRESS = "preference_progress";
private String Key_PROGRESS1 = "key_progress1";
private String Key1 = "key_value1";
private String PREFERENCE_PROGRESS1 = "preference_progress1";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences( PREFERENCE_PROGRESS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    currentProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt( Key_PROGRESS, 0 );

    sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences( PREFERENCE_PROGRESS1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    currentProgress1 = sharedPreferences1.getInt( Key_PROGRESS1, 0 );

    setContentView( R.layout.activity_apart );
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekbar );
    Seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekbar1 );
    int max = 5;
    seekBar.setMax( max );
    Seekbar.setMax( max );
    seekBar.setProgress( currentProgress );
    Seekbar.setProgress( currentProgress1 );
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( this );
    Seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( this );

}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    if (seekBar.getID() == R.id.seekbar) {
        newProgressValue = seekBar.getProgress();
        currentProgress = newProgressValue;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt( Key_PROGRESS, newProgressValue );

        editor.commit();

    } else {
        newProgressValue1 = seekBar.getProgress();
        currentProgress1 = newProgressValue;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
        editor.putInt( Key_PROGRESS1, newProgressValue1 );

        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

}

this should do what you wanted, but actually you should take a look a the correct patter to use when you develop in Android and java in general.

for instance you are using a seekbar and Seekbar, that's just impossible to read.